# Best Approach For CRUD

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have made my class static for database operation.All the methods like sql connection, insert , update , delete are also static. Is using static appropriate for CRUD operation if not what is the best method for CRud

public static class DBO
    {

```
    public static SqlConnection GetConnection()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconnection"].ConnectionString);
        if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            con.Open();
        }
        return con;
    }

    public static int IUD(string sql, SqlParameter[] param, CommandType cmdType)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = GetConnection())
        {

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
            cmd.CommandType = cmdType;

            if (param != null)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddRange(param);
            }
            try
            {
                return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }

        }
    }
    public static DataTable GetTable(string sql, SqlParameter[] param, CommandType cmdType)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = GetConnection())
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = cmdType;

                if (param != null)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddRange(param);
                }
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);

                return dt;

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you could code a machine language application to conect to a database, but the question would be the same:Why don't you want to use a provider?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  _providers_ are your way to say how to connect to a database. If your software needs to connect to a database, something should tell it how. that's a provider.

Comment: The connection is over TCP so you do it by implementing your own TCP connection.

Comment: yes, you can write your own database that does not need providers

Comment: @Pikoh,I was asked in exam if "Is there any technology to connect to database without using provider" thats why I want to know.

Comment: Well,of course you can access a database without a provider. How would a provider be able to connect to a database otherwise? A provider is a layer so you don't have to worry about the low levels details,but you could do it by yourself

Comment: BTW, maybe the question was about ODBC, that is not a provider...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly can. It surely will vary from one provider to another. You can take a peek into how [MySql .Net Connector](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-net) is implemented over here.

This raises the question, why would you want to do that?

Providers give you a standard API your application can depend on. That allows you to switch a provider at any time with a minimum amount of effort (obviously I'm completely ignoring possible sql syntactic differences between the target DBMS you choose).

If it's for academic purpose, hope the source of MySql .Net Connector helps you.